Why won't console.log run in if statement
I'm using supabase to authenticate users. I'm trying to return a message to the console if it fails however I can't get the console.log to work. I know the function is working because I can get it to redirect if there's an error, but I want to return the message as well
'use server'

import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

import { createClient } from '../../utils/supabase/server'

export async function login() {
  const supabase = await createClient()

  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInAnonymously()

  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
    // redirect('/anonlogin')
  } else {
    revalidatePath('/', 'layout')
    redirect('/')
  }
}


... return the message — what do you mean by that? If a console.log() does anything, it will be to print a log message at the server into the server log file or stream or whatever it is. If you want to send the error back to the client, then console.log() is not going to do that.

Oh, it won't return it into the console in the browser? How do I get a message to show up there?

ah i see where it's going now. hmm maybe this is fine

server component console logs won't display anything on browser, you can see those logs on the console where the next js server is running.
